# How do I get a CSS class to work in my Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get this class to show up with the var newCaption. Below the Javascript I have linked the CSS Class.

```
window.onload = function() {

var caption = document.getElementsByTagName("caption");
var oldCaption = caption[0].innerHTML;
var newCaption = oldCaption + "CAPTION";

caption[0].removeChild(caption[0].firstChild);
caption[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(newCaption));
```

Here's my CSS Class:

```
.hoverNode{
   background-color:#FFFFCC;
   border: solid 1px black;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   float:top;
   font-size:10pt;
   margin:5px;
   padding:3px;
   color:black;
}
```

Comment: Show you html. You should have a class="hoverNode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!

```
var caption = document.getElementsByTagName("caption");
var oldCaption = caption[0].innerHTML;
var newCaption = "CAPTION";

var span = document.createElement('span');
var text = document.createTextNode(newCaption);
span.appendChild(text);
span.className = "hoverNode";
caption[0].appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the class to the `caption` element.

```
caption.classList.add('hoverNode');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, the getElementByTagName() seems to be ignoring the caption. Perhaps because it is only permitted with a table as a parent.  It's showing an error that caption[0] is undefined.

Try changing your caption to a `p` and it seems to work.

```
window.onload = function() {

var caption = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var oldCaption = caption[0].innerHTML;
var newCaption = oldCaption + "CAPTION";

caption[0].removeChild(caption[0].firstChild);
caption[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(newCaption));
}
```

Of course you'll need a `<p>` element to add the text to.

```
<caption>Some text</caption>
<p>Some Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Or, if you surround your `<caption>` element with a `<table>` element it will also work.